# The alternative to xlwings and PIL module for Linux (Raspberry pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, openpyxl

I am in the process to move my python script code from my windows laptop to Raspberry pi device. However, I realized that I need to make some adjustments to make it works as in my windows laptop.

The thing I would make from this program is to generate the image (.png) from an excel report that will is usually updated twice in a day (morning and evening time)
I use xlwings module (to open the excel file and detect & select the active cell) and PIL module (to grab & save the selected cells as an image).

Here is the image sample:
[this image is generated from the excel file and new data will be added everyday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7W8l.png)

I read from another thread that xlwings module is specified for windows OS only and cannot be used for Raspberry pi. Is there an alternative for the xlwings and PIL for raspberry pi?

Below is my code that works well in windows but it doesn't work in my pi:

"**

```
import win32com.client
import xlwings as xw
from PIL import ImageGrab
import os
from datetime import datetime
import time

x = datetime.now()
print(x.strftime("%d%b%y"))
day = x.strftime("%d")
month = x.strftime("%b")
year = x.strftime("%y")

excelfilename = 'Argus ICI 4 Forward Prices SGX.xlsx'
path = r'C:\Users\asus\Desktop\KCH\Automation\SGX\%s' %excelfilename

imagename = 'SGX Data Image %s' %(x.strftime("%d%b%y")) + '.png'
pathimage= r'C:\Users\asus\Desktop\KCH\Automation\SGX\%s' %imagename

print("Image file name: ", imagename)

app=xw.App(visible=True, add_book=False)
wb=app.books.open(path)
sheet=wb.sheets[0]
all=sheet.used_range

#print(all.value)
all.api.CopyPicture()
sheet.api.Paste()
pic=sheet.pictures[0]
pic.api.Copy()
time.sleep(3)
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
img.save(pathimage)

wb.close()
app.quit()
```

**"

I am so confused now and would really appreciate any help on this matter, thank you.

Comment: To make the screenshot you need Excel; Excel doesn't run on Linux. You could try doing the same with OpenOffice, LibreOffice or maybe using a browser running Office online.

Comment: @CharlieClark yeah i noticed that too. But i can process the excel file, such as adding new data set to the excel file using openpyxl module. However, for the xlwings module, i read that is only available for windows.. so i am trying to find similar module that works for linux but have no idea so far :(

Comment: You won't find a similar module for Linux because xlwings uses Excel. OpenOffice, etc. has Python bindings.